# Running hadoop example jobs result in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop

I am running one of the packaged examples inside the hadoop-examples-1.0.3.jar file: specifially PiEstimator as follows:

```
hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.3.jar pi 5 10
```

THis is failing though, with ClassNotFoundException:

```
Number of Maps  = 5
Samples per Map = 10
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Wrote input for Map #2
Wrote input for Map #3
Wrote input for Map #4
Starting Job
13/06/14 19:42:07 INFO mapred.JobClient: Default number of map tasks: 5
13/06/14 19:42:07 INFO mapred.JobClient: Default number of reduce tasks: 1
13/06/14 19:42:07 INFO security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping: add hadoop to shell userGroupsCache
13/06/14 19:42:07 INFO mapred.JobClient: Setting group to hadoop
13/06/14 19:42:07 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 5
13/06/14 19:42:08 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201306141855_0004
13/06/14 19:42:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/06/14 19:42:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201306141855_0004_m_000006_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)

attempt_201306141855_0004_m_000006_0: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
attempt_201306141855_0004_m_000006_0: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
attempt_201306141855_0004_m_000006_0:   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
attempt_201306141855_0004_m_000006_0:   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
attempt_201306141855_0004_m_000006_0:   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
attempt_201306141855_0004_m_000006_0:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
attempt_201306141855_0004_m_000006_0:   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
attempt_201306141855_0004_m_000006_0:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
attempt_201306141855_0004_m_000006_0: Could not find the main class: .  Program will exit.
13/06/14 19:42:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201306141855_0004_r_000002_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 1.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)
```

Now I looked at the job.xml file and found the generated mapred.jar and downloaded it from hdfs:

From JobTracker UI:

```
mapred.jar  hdfs://10.172.86.250:9000/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_201306141855_0001/job.jar
```

Download it to local and view it:

```
hadoop dfs -get hdfs://10.172.86.250:9000/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_201306141855_0001/job.jar .
```

Now the PiEstimator class IS in there:

```
jar -tvf job.jar | grep Pi

  2711 Fri May 17 00:14:04 UTC 2013 org/apache/hadoop/examples/MultiFileWordCount.class
  1504 Fri May 17 00:14:04 UTC 2013 org/apache/hadoop/examples/PiEstimator$HaltonSequence.class
  3101 Fri May 17 00:14:04 UTC 2013 org/apache/hadoop/examples/PiEstimator$PiMapper.class
  3883 Fri May 17 00:14:04 UTC 2013 org/apache/hadoop/examples/PiEstimator$PiReducer.class
  7140 Fri May 17 00:14:04 UTC 2013 org/apache/hadoop/examples/PiEstimator.class
```

So .. hint/help appreciated . btw I have run many hundreds of m/r jobs across dozens of clusters, so this is not exactly a noobie question. However, I have not encountered this particular failure mode before.

Comment: From the error information `Could not find the main class: .  Program will exit.`, it seems that JVM can not start as the main class is an empty string (Here I think it should have been `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child`). Could you try other jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Commmand Line was getting garbled (-Xmx options). It